# Set up seperate CSS files for Apps Script UI Service

Tags: css, google-apps-script

With Apps Script UI service, the CSS Styling can be set with the `setStyleAttributes()` method of the various classes.

[setStyleAttributes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/grid#setStyleAttributes%28Object%29)

Multiple CSS style attributes can be set at the same time with `setStyleAttributes()`.  The CSS style settings can be put into an `key:value` object assigned to a variable, and then the variable can be used in the `setStyleAttributes` method.

```
var cssHome = {"color":"red", "cursor": "pointer", "textDecoration" : "underline", "fontSize": "small", "font-family":"Arial Black"}
var menuHome = app.createMenuItem('HOME')
menuHome.setStyleAttributes(cssHome)
```

Right now all my code and variables are in one `.gs` file, and everything is in the `doGet` function.  Is there a way to put the CSS into another file, and call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are happy authoring the CSS as key value pairs you could either wrap them in a separate function and call it at value assignment or you could store in a flat file in Drive and UrlFetch it. Neither solution allows for conventional CSS authoring but does you ask.

As it is for a doGet the former might be preferable. You could reuse this styling across multiple scripts by wrapping in another GS and referencing it as a library.

If you used HtmlService instead of UiService your CSS options are increased by convention.

Comment: I'm just going to put the variable declarations in another `.gs` file.  Apps Script will search other files for variable names.  So, even though I'm putting my CSS in a `.gs` file instead of a `html` file, it's in it's own separate file.  A regular CSS file would have something like the Tag name -- #ReferenceName {CSS here}  The only difference is, now I'm making what would be the tag name, a variable name `var ReferenceName = {CSS Here}`

Comment: I would gladly use JUST the HTML Service, and not the UI service, but I can't find a way to upload files from the users drive to Google Drive through the HTML Service.